# Webpack external attribute meaning

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm reading a react project. In this project, they defined an external like this:

```
webpackConfig.externals = {}
webpackConfig.externals['react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment'] = true
webpackConfig.externals['react/lib/ReactContext'] = true
webpackConfig.externals['react/addons'] = true
```

I have read Webpack document but I still don't understand above lines. What is the meaning when define those configurations ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's environment. This feature is typically most useful to library developers, however there are a variety of applications for it.

It is used to build a library with webpack that has dependencies to other libraries which should not be included in the compiled version. The `externals` option defines dependencies that should be resolved in the target environment.

Check these links for more explanation: 
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/externals
http://tomasalabes.me/blog/_site/web-development/2016/04/30/Webpack-Series-Part-1.html

Comment: I don't really understand this. so in my example, why `reac/lib/` should not be included in the compiled version. thanks.

Comment: It simply prevents bundling of certain imported packages, and instead relies on them being retrieved at runtime, they should be available in the target environment, from a CDN for example